# Dynamic values for High Charts in flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, highcharts

I am new to flex. I am using flash builder. I wanted to display heatmap in my flex application. hence i displayed heatmap(Highcharts) as a html page in flex using Iframe. Here is my code to display heatmap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:flexiframe="http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >
<flexiframe:IFrame id="googleIFrame"
 label="Google"
 source="heatMap.html"
 width="80%"
 height="80%"/>
</s:Application>
HeatMap is been dispalyed. I want to dynamically set the values for heatmap. i am retrieving values form java class method. how to set those values to heatmap in flex?
```

Here is my heatmap.html

```
 !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>
Chart
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 80
},

title: {
        text: 'Usage '
},

xAxis: {
        categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura']
},

yAxis: {
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
        title: null
},

colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#5858FA',
        maxColor: '#FF0000'
},

legend: {
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y:5,
        symbolHeight: 280
},

tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
}
},

series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: [[0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 4], [0, 2, 6], [0, 3, 8], [0, 4, 10], [1, 0, 12], [1, 1, 14], [1, 2, 15], [1, 3, 25], [1, 4, 24], [2, 0, 23], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 25], [2, 3, 15], [2, 4, 10], [3, 0, 20], [3, 1, 13], [3, 2, 14], [3, 3, 15], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 13], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 10], [4, 4, 15], [5, 0, 8], [5, 1, 22], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 10], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 9], [6, 2, 8], [6, 3, 9], [6, 4, 6], [7, 0, 13], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 12], [7, 3, 33], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 25], [8, 1, 17], [8, 2, 23], [8, 3, 24], [8, 4, 20], [9, 0, 18], [9, 1, 14], [9, 2, 11], [9, 3, 18], [9, 4, 11]],
        dataLabels: {

}
}]

});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 320px; width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto">    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do i pass the values returned from java method to HeatMap?

I am calling java method using Http service

```
<mx:DataGrid x="320" y="550" dataProvider="{srv.lastResult}"/>
<fx:Declarations>
<!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
<s:HTTPService id="srv" url="http://localhost:8080/JavaFlex/rest/flextest">
</s:HTTPService>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Comment: Are you able to return JSON in your Java? If yes, then you can call $.getJSON in javascript and load data, initialising chart.

Comment: In java script function java I am not able to access the HighChart instance

Comment: How about my question?